# Can I define a measurable function using base of a topology?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

We know the more general definition of a measurable funnction: let $(X,\mathcal{X})$ and $(Y,\tau)$ a measurable and topological space, respectively. The function $f:X\to Y$ is a $\mathcal{X}$-measurable function if $f^{-1}(V) \in \mathcal{X}$, $\forall V \in \tau$.

I would like to know if it is true that we can define the measurability of the function $f$ using a base of the topology $\tau$. That is, suposse that $\beta$ is a base of $\tau$. Then, I wold like to prove that

$$f \hbox{ is } \mathcal{X}\hbox{-measurable function} \Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{X},\quad \forall B \in \beta $$

We know that any $V \in \tau$ can be written as

$$V = \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{g}} A,\quad \mathcal{g} \subset \beta$$

with $g$  not necessarily enumerable. One implication of my goal is trivial. Any element of $\beta$ is open, that is, it is a element of $\tau$. Then, if $f$  is  $\mathcal{X}$-measurable function, then $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{X}, \forall B \in \beta$. But, because $g \in \beta$ is not necessarily enumerable, I can not conclude the other implication. That is, I can not conclude that

$$f^{-1}(V) = \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{g}} f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{X}$$

I would like to know if it is possible to circumvent this or in what cases this result is valid.

Comment: If the $Y$ is second countable the any open set is a countable union of sets from the base, so you get measurability. In general you cannot  conclude that $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Tell me more about this property. Are metric spaces  second countable?

Comment: A metric space is second countable iff it is separable (in the sense there is a countable subset which is dense). A standard example of a metric space which is not separable is $\ell ^{\infty}$ the space of all bounded sequences of real numbers with the metric $d((a_n),(b_n))=\sup\{|a_n-b_n|:n\geq 1\}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is separable because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathbb{R}$ has a enumerable base. Can I conclude that $\{(q_1,q_2) , q_1 < q_2 , q_i \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is a base of the topology of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: All Euclidean spaces are separable (hence second countable) so your definition of measurability works. Intervals with rational end points form a countable base in $\mathbb R$, rectangles with rational coordinatesform a countable base in $\mathbb R^{2}$, etc.

Comment: Measurability is about measures. Continuity is about open sets. It is true that for Borel sets the collection of Borel sets is determined by the topology. But this is not generally the case in arbitrary measures and arbitrary spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is too long for the comment section.**

You are probably after the following result. On any set $\mathrm{Z},$ denote by $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$ the minimal sigma algebra containing the subset $\mathscr{A}$ of the power set of $\mathrm{Z}$. If $\varphi$ is a function with values in $\mathrm{Z},$ we also denote by $\varphi(\mathscr{A})$ the set of $\varphi^{-1}(\mathrm{A})$ as $\mathrm{A}$ runs through $\mathscr{A}.$

**Proposition.** Let $f$ be any function $\mathrm{X} \to \mathrm{Y}$ and let $\mathscr{Y}$ be any subset of the power set of $\mathrm{Y}.$ Then, $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathscr{Y})) = \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathscr{Y})).$

*Proof.* You probably already know that the set of preimages of a sigma algebra conforms a sigma algebra, this proves at once the $\supset.$ For the other side, consider the set $\mathscr{Y}'$ of sets $\mathrm{E}$ in $\sigma(\mathscr{Y})$ such that $f^{-1}(\mathrm{E}) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathscr{Y})).$ Straightforwardly, $\mathscr{Y}'$ is a sigma field containing $\mathscr{Y},$ hence, it also contains $\mathscr{Y},$ this proves $\subset.$ Q.E.D.